# Can not find symbol class RTCClientVideoTracksCallback

Tags: android, callback, videochat, connectycube

I tried to implement Connectycube on Android for Video Call, after following instruction from their web including adding their library under app.gradle but when build there an error on VideoConversationFragment.java with msg 'Error:(27, 44) error: cannot find symbol class RTCClientVideoTracksCallback' . Is there any step I missed or any problem?

Thank you
On Build Gradle :

```
implementation 'com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-chat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-adding their 
li:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-storage:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk- 
pushnotifications:1.0.2'
```

On BaseConversationFragment.java :

```
 import com.connectycube.videochat.callbacks.RTCClientVideoTracksCallback;
```

and this is code where the error comes up.

```
 public class VideoConversationFragment extends BaseConversationFragment implements Serializable, RTCClientVideoTracksCallback<RTCSession>, RTCSessionStateCallback<RTCSession>, RTCSessionEventsCallback {
```

Comment: show the code wher you ge tthis error

Comment: add it to the question and format please

Comment: This is the code for import    `import com.connectycube.videochat.callbacks.RTCClientVideoTracksCallback;`   and this is code where the error comes up.  `public class VideoConversationFragment extends BaseConversationFragment implements Serializable, RTCClientVideoTracksCallback<RTCSession>, RTCSessionStateCallback<RTCSession>, RTCSessionEventsCallback {`

Comment: `add it to the question and format please` Don't add to comment

Comment: Apologize, I don't understand. I'm new in here. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: don't put the code in comments. Edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, Apologize. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTCClientVideoTracksCallback belongs to videochat module.

Please make sure that you have added the following dependency:

```
implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-videochat:1.0.2"
```

I do not see it in the list of dependencies in your code. Here is also the [guide](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/videocalling?id=connect-videochat-sdk) for your reference.